# How to compute within-subjects confidence intervals (Loftus-Masson or Cousineau-Morey)?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I need to calculate within-subjects' confidence intervals in R for a plot I am creating. Does anyone know how to construct either the Loftus-Masson confidence intervals or the Cousineau-Morey confidence intervals in R?

I have been trying to find out how to do this for hours.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The package `superb` for R lets you do that directly. The adjustments are obtained with a list of adjustments, in your case

```
adjustments = list(purpose = "difference", decorrelation = "CM")
```

that, is, with no programming at all. The resulting plot is a ggplot2 object so that you can customize it as you wish. The full documentation is available at

[dcousin3.github.io/superb/](https://dcousin3.github.io/superb/)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for this: from the man himself! Thanks a lot.